# How can I estimate the sensitivity of a bond ETF's price to interest rate changes?

Tags: interest-rate, etf, bonds, risk

Is there a standard method for estimating the sensitivity of a bond ETF's price to interest rate changes?  Some of the information I have includes the average duration and the SEC yield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duration is the time weighted average maturity, more or less.

The value of the ETF will drop as a function of the duration times the change in rates.  For example, if the duration is 8 years, a .1% increase in rates will cause a drop of .8%.